# SQL: Given one record, how to find all its associated child records without knowing the number of levels in the hierarchy?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains ID and ParentID. I need to find all the related child records of a given record.

[SQL FIddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13211)

or

```
 Create table #Temp
(
    ID varchar(10)
   ,ParentID varchar(10)
   ,Name varchar(20)
)

Insert into #Temp
    values
     ('001','002','a')
    ,('002','003','b')
    ,('003',NULL,'c')
    ,('004','003','d')
    ,('005','002','e')
    ,('006','005','f')
    ,('007','008','g')
    ,('008','006','h')
    ,('009','005','i')
    ,('010','009','j')
    ,('011','005','k')
    ,('012','010','l')
    ,('013','010','m')
```

For example, given ID='005', i want to find its all child records.

```
Results would be ID 006,008,009,010,011,012,013
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: You can do it with a [recursive cte](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

Comment: Note that `007` should be in your answer because 007 --> 008 --> 006 --> 005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a recursive cte which gives you the answer:

```
; with cte as (

  select ID, parentid, name from temp where parentid = '005'

  union all

  select t.ID, t.parentid, t.name from temp t
  join cte c on c.id=t.parentid
)

select * from cte
```

See fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e74d/4

Answer (score 1):

This requires a recursive CTE.  Assuming that your data is really a tree and has no cycles:

```
with cte as (
      select id, parentid
      from #Temp
      where parentid = '005'
      union all
      select child.id, cte.id
      from cte join
           #Temp child
           on cte.id = child.parentid
     )
select distinct id
from cte;
```